# map color / opacity / shade... i don't know exactly how to describe it

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I just saw http://www.meetbymaps.com/
I have many questions, hopefully you guys could help:

1) Does that blue world (while the map loads , it might take you 2
secs to see it at first if you have fast internet connection) is a
custom image they did? On what event have they put it? i wanted to
created something like that as well.

2) How did they give the map that blue feeling (you can zoom in and
see for your self)

3) Positioning of the controls, is that the regular positioning
(adding to the control pane) or something custom... mootools?

Thanks a lot , waiting for your help

Dex.

Comment: I can only answer the first one. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jkxfv/

You need map styling, there's a tutorial here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
and read the API Reference to learn more.

There's also a wizard http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: Thanks, great!!! :)
Are you sure (1) is using map styles? and not some sort of image?

Waiting for more answers relating question (3)

Comment: No, I'm not sure (1) is styles. I didn't look at the source code. I was thinking it was one way of replicating the effect.

Comment: After playing with it for a bit, i can say (after looking at their resource), they've used an image, regarding (3), regular positioning.
Heitor Chang: thanks again, great answers.. 
i'm new here so if i should reward you with points, let me know..  tnx =]

Comment: Thanks for offering, right now I have all the points I need. I'll give you a few. I think it's allowed :)

Comment: Haha :)
Tnx again! I'd follow your answers if i'd know its possible here